# GCP composer read MySql table and push into GCS and then into BigQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow

We are using GCP Cloud composer 2 (Airflow managed) as orchestral tools and BigQuery as DB. I need to push all the records from MySQL table into GCS cloud bucket and BigQuery table but the method should be upsert. So I wrote below DAG but it fails saying "airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to BigQueryUpsertTableOperator (task_id: load_to_bigquery). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: 'table_id', Schema_fields,schema_update_options': ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'], 'write_disposition': 'WRITE_APPEND', 'source_format': 'CSV', 'source_objects': "

I want to know if these arguments are not available in the BigQueryUpsertTableOperator then how should i do Upsert operation from MySQL to GCS and then to Bigquery and also how should i pull incremental data from MySql table after initial run. I want MySQL to be in sync with GCS and BigQuery always and for the same of which please help me. Also i want the Schema to be given by me externally since some columns are coming with incorrect datatypes from MySQL to GCS and as you see in the error, i can't use Schema_fields since it's not an attribute of BigQueryUpsertTableOperator.

Here is my DAG code -

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.mysql_to_gcs import MySQLToGCSOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSDeletefilesOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryUpsertTableOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models import Variable

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('archival_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='0 0 * * *')

# Get last execution date of the DAG
last_execution_date = Variable.get('last_execution_date', default_var=None)

if last_execution_date is None:
    # This is the first run, fetch all data from MySQL table
    query = "SELECT * FROM bkp_item_22_02_2023;"
else:
    # This is not the first run, fetch only incremental data
    query = f"SELECT * FROM bkp_item_22_02_2023 WHERE file_updated >= '{last_execution_date}'"

bucket = 'us-central1-bucket'
file_name = 'data/{{ds_nodash}}.csv'

# Create a task to upload the data to GCS
upload_to_gcs = MySQLToGCSOperator(
    task_id='upload_to_gcs',
    sql=query,
    bucket=bucket,
    filename=file_name,
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_conn_id',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    export_format='CSV',
    dag=dag
)

# Create a task to load the data from GCS to BigQuery
load_to_bigquery = BigQueryUpsertTableOperator(
    task_id='load_to_bigquery',
    dataset_id='testing',
    table_id='item_bkp_22022023',
    schema_fields=[
        {
    "name": "Id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "item_type_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "user_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "image_info",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "BYTES"
  },
  {
    "name": "text_info",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "location_info",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "item_date_time",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "name": "latitude",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "name": "longitude",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "FLOAT"
  },
  {
    "name": "parcel_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "shipment_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "transaction_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "web_hook_status",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "file_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "file_created",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "name": "file_updated",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
  },
  {
    "name": "pickup_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "team_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "driver_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "name": "container_id",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  }
    ],
    schema_update_options=['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'],
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    source_format='CSV',
    source_files=[f'{bucket}/{file_name}'],
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    table_resource={"tableId": "item_bkp_22022023", "datasetId": "testing", "projectId": "test-dev"},
    dag=dag
)

# Set the execution date for the next run
Variable.set('last_execution_date', datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

# Define task dependencies
upload_to_gcs >> load_to_bigquery
```

Answer (score 0):

The BigQueryUpsertTableOperator only "upserts" the table schema, not the table data.
So, if the table exists, it will update the schema. If not, then creates it.

To load a file from GCS, you have to use [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery.GCSToBigQueryOperator), but it only inserts data. So a suggest you insert data in a stage table, then executes a MERGE comand on Bigquery to upsert your official table